# How can I search my Favourites in Chrome and stock on my S3?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I have thousands of favourites in  my stock browser and chrome and every time I'm looking for a specific link I have to scroll through a lot. If I start typing in a word in the URL box in either browser that I'm sure is in the title of the link it never finds it!!  Any tools  out there to help? I tried several bookmark managers from Google Play it always crashes or the app is never able to load my thousands.  Or the app will duplicate links a lot and I 
ended up with 11,000 faves once.  I'd like to be able to search all the favourites of every browser at one time.  Any help?

OS: 4.1 
S3

Comment: I am using chrome beta and it succesfully finds my favourites when I start typing in the top bar (or even the bar on the home screen) could you try installing chrome beta and seeing if it works?

Comment: @ollie: but I need to search all the favourites at one time or then I have to open each browser separately searching for stuff.

Comment: So you want a method of merging favourites from different browsers, I would recommend you give up in the stock browser, and move your favourites to chrome